# Run a function in scala with a list as input

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I'M very nooby with Scala, so what I'm trying to do is execute a function that gets as a parameter a list created previously. Then I go thru the whole list reading every element in lower case to find a keyword.

Finally, I count how many times is the word and return the value.My project is created as a Scala class, by the way in my code seems like the lower case it's not working to read every list element in the lower case.

If I move all my code outside of a function that works but I don't understand why in a functional approach it doesn't go thru.

Please guys, give me a hand to figure it out, thanks
AU

code:

```
object practiqueI extends App{
//exercise 1
/*  val liste = List(15,39,22,98,37,19,5)
  var z : Int = 0

  for (i <- liste){

    z = z + i
  }

  println("the total is:",z)*/

//exercise 2
  val list_txt = List("Introduction à la programmation ",
    "Practique de la programmation",
    "Structure de données",
    "principe de la programmation",
    "Algorithme","Langages de programmation")


  def wordrepeted(some: _*) : Int =  {
    var  counter_word:Int = 0
    var counter_nword: Int =0
    val word_cle: String = "programmation"
    var exist_word: Boolean = false

    for (i <- some) {
      var test: String = i.toLowerCase
      if (test.contains(word_cle)) {
        counter_word +=  1
        exist_word = true
       } else {
         counter_nword += 1
      }
    }
    return counter_nword
  }

  wordrepeted(list_txt)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first if you want to have method that takes list of strings, then it should look like:

```
def myMethod(someList: List[String]) = {...}
```

Second, scala's `List` provides methods to look through its elements like `find()`, `exist()`, `count()` etc. I strongly recommend to use them. Those methods takes Boolean functions as parameters. Fe. checking if list contains element that contains certain substring will look like:

```
someList.exists(s => s.contains("programmation"))
```

Counting elements that contain that substring is very similar:

```
someList.count(s => s.contains("programmation"))
```

Third thing, you do not need to use `return` statement in Scala, last expression is taken as return value.

So basically your method to count elements containing substring would look like:

```
def countElements(allElements: List[String], substring: String): Int = 
    allElements.count(s => s.toLowerCase.contains(substring.toLowerCase))
```

Looks like you had some experience with other programming language but Scala is pretty new for you. Before moving to exercises like this I really recommend going through some tutorial like: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/index.htm just to learn how some things works in Scala as it has lot of syntactic sugars and useful 'shortcuts'.

Comment: how can you in a method define two return elements, for instance in the example you made at the end you return an Int, but what if you would like to return 2 Ints? thanks

Comment: You can change method return type to `Tuple2[Int, Int]`. Tuple can be easily created by closing 2 variables inside brackets fe.: `(int1, int2)`. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_tuples.htm